# Jquery Mobile - Programmatically set footer to fixed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've been hacking about with jquery mobile, and I've finally got the dialogs to work how I want them to (as an overlay, NOT as a separate page).

The problem I have is if I have the footer set to fixed, open my dialog, then close it, the footer changes to static.

I need the JS to tell jquery mobile to get my #footer back to fixed.

Comment: Finally found it!

Thanks for the help Rory, but I was looking to turn jquery mobile's magical (and crap) auto footer back on.

What I did was hide the footer on load of dialog, and when I unloaded the dialog I used this line:

    $.mobile.fixedToolbars.show(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it!

Thanks for the help Rory, but I was looking to turn jquery mobile's magical (and crap) auto footer back on.

What I did was hide the footer on load of dialog, and when I hid the dialog and reloaded the page I called this line:

```
$.mobile.fixedToolbars.show(true);
```

Sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#footer").css("position", "fixed");
```

If that's not what you meant, please add more detail to your question.